# Compile Code Error Help

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, class, code

I keep testing Jeff Douglas' Dynamic search controller and I'm getting a compile error code.


 
Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Contact.interested_technologies__c.getDescribe() at line 81 column 44


Here's his code....

```
// use apex describe to build the picklist values
  public List<String> technologies {
    get {
      if (technologies == null) {

        technologies = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Contact.interested_technologies__c.getDescribe();

        for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues())
          technologies.add(f.getLabel());

      }
      return technologies;          
    }
    set;
  }
```

Any suggestion?  I have no error on another sandbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error because you don't have picklist interested_technologies__c field on contact object. Create field interested_technologies__c with picklist values on your contact object ur code will work fine.

for example following code will not give any error.

```
   Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Contact.LeadSource.getDescribe();

for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues()){
          system.debug(f.getLabel());

      }
```

[image]